# How to add additional dynamic params to the external script in index.html? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an external script in Vuejs inside index.html

```
<script>window.appSettings={app_id:"appId"};</script>
```

I need to pass `username` and `userEmail` from `getters/user` like this:

```
<script>window.appSettings={app_id:"appId", contact_name: "Alexander the Great",
        contact_email: "alex@empire.com",};</script>
```

How can this be achieved correctly?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, do you have userId and userEmail inside your Vue application and you want to add these to window.appSettings, or is it the other way around, userId and userEmail are in window.appSettings and you want to use these values inside your Vue application?

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe It's clear in Vuejs. I have a getter that has those values. I need to pass those values inside the external script object. Because after that external script there is another external script that is going to use that data for identification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timing will be an issue. Inside Vue you can write to window.appSettings at any time. I'd suggest you do this inside a created or mounted function.

an example:

```
{
   mounted() {
      window.appSettings = window.appSettings || {};
      window.appSettings.userId = this.userId;
   }
}
```

Because an external script will use these values it's important that Vue writes these values BEFORE the external script is loaded.

To ensure Vue get's to write first and then the script is loaded, it is best to make Vue responsible for loading the external script. You could do this with by dynamically creating and script element and adding it to the dom, like so:

```
{
   mounted() {
      // write the values first
      window.appSettings = window.appSettings || {};
      window.appSettings.userId = this.userId;

      // now load any external scripts:
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'hellozest.io/widget/...';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
   }
}
```

This strategy may work but as you can see Vue needs to know about external scripts and is responsible for loading them. In general I'd prefer to solve this in a different way:

Is userId and userEmail available to you on the backend side of your application? Then you could write the 'window.appSettings` on the server and let the Vue application be as simple as it should.

If only Vue knows about userId and userEmail you could decide to isolate this responsibility inside one vue component, because it is important to keep this code in one place.

Comment: I tried this dynamic script writing. It might not work because it's a js logic inside script tag not the source  atribute. Also there is a second script that is getting loaded after first appSettings script.

Comment: JS Logic inside script tag, you mean like a google analytics loader script?

Comment: <script>window.appSettings={app_id:"appId"};</script> like this and after this script it runs second external script with different long js logic inside second script tag:
<script>(function(){window.addEventListener("load",function(){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,t.src="https://hellozest.io/widget/"+window.zestSettings.app_id,document.body.appendChild(t)});})();</script>

Comment: Ah, I see, this is a lot like a google analytics loader. In script basically adds a script element to the body like we do, so you could extract the t.src (the source) and let Vue load the script.

Comment: So second script is depended to the first script

Comment: I got a bit confused. So can you please edit your answer based on these samples?

Comment: I've updated the example. Keep only the first script tag with '<script>window.appSettings..</script>' and remove the second script tag that loads hellozest.io'

Comment: Thanks, and what should I do with this?
function(){window.addEventListener("load",function(){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0

Comment: Yes that is the second script that loads hellozest.io, you may remove that

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. The last question isn't it better to modify the last part as: src = { type: 'text/javascript' async: !0, src: '/....' }

Comment: No, you cannot assign an object to `src`, you may add `script.async = true; script.defer = tr`; script.type = 'text/javascript'` to the Vue created function I demonstrated. These are minor improvements.